# Send and receive Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) raw packets on Linux

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there an easy way to send and receive BLE raw packets on Linux, e.g. Raspberry Pi devices?  Very simply, I would like to use BLE as packet radio, i.e. exchange data packets over the air among several devices.  Every device knows the MAC address of all other devices.  The BLE packet format is very straightforward.  I would think one should be able to put user data into the PDU (2~257 bytes) then push it through a `socket` to be sent out through the BLE PHY, just like how one can send raw UDP packets through a NIC.  But I cannot figure out a straightforward way to achieve this after quite a bit of investigation.  I suppose `hcitool cmd` could send packets if used correctly?  But its usage is very cryptic.

Comment: One simple way of communicating between two BLE devices is to use a simulated "UART". A UART provides a bi-directional byte stream, so that both ends of a connection can transmit and receive bytes with each other. A commonly used BLE UART services is the Nordic UART Service (NUS).https://developer.nordicsemi.com/nRF_Connect_SDK/doc/1.4.0/nrf/include/bluetooth/services/nus.html

Comment: The BLE UART service or anything based on GATT characteristics requires establishing some sort of connection (or pairing, though it may not need manual intervention), then the BLE stack handles the link management, packet retransmit etc.  When the link quality is bad, it is a lot of hassle (and long latency) for the user code to interact with the stack to figure out if the link is still there, if a re-connect is needed etc.  It is actually easier to just send/receive unreliable UDP-like packet and let user code to handle the loss of packets.  But I cannot find how to do this with BLE.

Comment: Perhaps WiFi is a better option for this (as far as using built-in PHY goes, otherwise one could use a variety of specialized external RF modules).  WiFi can be put into monitor mode to send and raw packets without `connection'.  This project https://github.com/svpcom/wifibroadcast demonstrates this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node client/server functions here do exactly this: exchange raw packets via BLE over a network of Pis. See section 3.7 in the documentation for NODE connections.

https://github.com/petzval/btferret

Comment: What an excellent project, especially the documentation!  I think I've got sufficient information from it to use hci directly to achieve what I wanted to do.